# Can I use Visual Studio Code to create/publish SSIS packages?

Tags: visual-studio, ssis, visual-studio-code

Can I use Visual Studio Code to create/publish SSIS packages?

If so, what are the benefits of using Visual Studio Professional (instead of the free Visual Studio Code product)?

---

The comparison on the Visual Studio site doesn't provide much help: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

Also, I cannot use Visual Studio Community edition due to its limited licensing for use at companies.

Comment: 99% no. A DTSX package is an XML document but the components themselves are COM or .NET classes bundled with their own designers. I doubt anyone wants to work with raw XML

Comment: The free Visual Studio product is Visual Studio Community, which has the same features as Professional. SSIS editing is provided by SQL Server Data Tools, which is available as a free standalone product or as a payload in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you cannot use Visual Studio Code to create SSIS packages, but you also do not need Visual Studio Professional. You can use [SQL Server Data Tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-2017), which you can install during your Visual Studio installation or install with the stand-alone installer.

If you are only doing T-SQL and SSIS development, then you probably don't need Visual Studio Professional. I don't think there is anything SSDT is missing regarding SSIS development. Saying that, I currently use Professional, but I used to use just SSDT, and I never ran into any limitations concerning SSIS development.

Comment: SSDT comes as a standalone download or as a Visual Studio option, it doesn't come with SQL Server.

Comment: My link is to the standalone installer.  "Comes with SQL Server" might be misleading, but I was trying to communicate that there is no cost to use SSDT. I by no means meant that you have to install SQL Server on your local machine to install SSDT. I edited it. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: I'm not sure about all the implications but, have you checked [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/integration-services/ssis-quickstart-deploy-tsql-vscode?view=sql-server-2017) ?

Comment: @BtcSources That has no bearing on the ability to create packages with VS Code.  It is "to connect to the SSIS Catalog database, and then use Transact-SQL statements to deploy an SSIS project to the SSIS Catalog".